# Why would I get 8 hex digits when I specify "%.2x"

Tags: c, hex

I want to print the hex representation of a floating-point number, but there are some `f`s being printed unexpectedly.

Here is the code I'm using:

```c
float f = 0.2;
char *ptr = (char*)&f;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++)
    printf("%.2x\n", ptr[i]);
```

This is what I got:

```
ffffffcd
ffffffcc
4c
3e
```

Comment: Don't post image of code. Anyway, that's because `char` is apparently signed on your system. Use `unsigned char`.

Comment: Also, `%2f` in your code doesn't match `%.2f` in the question title.

Comment: @Jester Sorry I am a newbie, thank you for letting me know the rules here.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I tried both of them and got the same result, but I forgot to change it back before screenshotting.

Comment: I believe that `char` is `signed char` on every system. Also, better to use `sizeof(f)` than `sizeof(float)` in this case (allows you to change the type in a single place in your code).

Comment: @goodvibration: The ARM and AArch64 ABIs use `char = unsigned char`.  Many others including all(?) x86 ABIs use `char = signed char`.  https://godbolt.org/z/KpDERh shows that `char c = -1` zero-extends to `int 255` on ARM but sign-extends to `int -1` on x86.  ISO C leaves it implementation-defined, and yes some mainstream real-world implementations do make different choices.

Comment: @goodvibration Thank you for your advice, but why it matters to use "unsigned char" if both unsigned and signed char are 1 byte.

Comment: The length spec defines *padding and alignment* **not** *truncation*. If the data is too long for the field width, the correct data is printed, not the incorrect data.

Comment: Because `printf` converts it to an `int`, and an `int` of negative value starts with a bunch of "ff"s as you might know already by now.

Comment: The fomat `%x` is for `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Das_Geek Thank you for editing and thank you all for answering my question.

Comment: @Jimmy As a rule of thumb, don't post pictures of code to any forum ever.  This is literally never the right way to share your code.  The reason for this is that others cannot quote your code or compile it for themselves or show you a fixed version without having it in an editable form, which a picture is not.

Comment: @PeterCordes your godbolt link just shows the compiler default setting, you can change it with `-fsigned-char` or `-funsigned-char` on gcc.  Is there actually any binary incompatibility involved?

Answer (score 0):

The code causes undefined behaviour by using an incorrect format specifier. `%x` is only for `unsigned int`, but you give an argument of type `char` .

You could fix this by changing the type of `ptr`:

```
unsigned char *ptr = (char*)&f;
```

Technically the argument to printf should be cast to `unsigned int` but it's generally considered safe to rely on non-negative values promoted to `int` even for `%x`.

Comment: you should be able to just typecast it in the printf